# Compilation error when trying to obtain a pointer to the size of a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a `std::vector<int>` instance called `arr`, and I want to work with its length using pointers.

My declaration

```
unsigned int *ptr = &arr.size();
```

gives me a compilation error:

```
cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long').
```

This error persisted even after I changed the type of the pointer to `size_t`.

What is the problem here?

Comment: The `arr.size()` returns `size_t` (i.e. `unsigned long long`).

Comment: And if you don't know what datatype to put, simply use `auto`.

Comment: You can’t take it’s address. It’s function return value. There’s no object to take the address of. There are only instructions to make an object (it’s a prvalue). You can store the size into a variable (actually create an object) and take the address of that, but this will not update when the vector’s size changes and changes to it will not affect the vector.

Comment: @RohanBari in this case, "size_t" is "unsigned long", not "unsigned long long". The error message says so.

Comment: @HTNW the definition says `size_t` is `typedef unsigned long long size_t`.

Comment: Why do you want that? What do you want to achieve that you can't achieve by calling `size()` again?

Comment: @RohanBari [The specification says it is implementation defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t). It can change depending on architecture, OS, compiler, standard library, and potentially the phase of the moon. You can’t say what it is in general; that’s why the name size_t exists, so you can refer to "the type of indices on this system" without caring about what type that actually is. The definition on your system is apparently different from OP’s. The error message from OP’s system is the one that’s important. In any case, OP should write just “size_t” anyway.

Comment: Please be more specific than "work with its length".  And read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @WernerHenze Just for the sake of using pointers and getting accustomed to them. Thanks to all of you here for explaining me, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Mihail -- There is a time and place for pointer usage, and your use case is not a time or place to use them.

Comment: I would be very happy if downvoters let me know what I can improve next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
std::vector<int> arr;
unsigned int* ptr = &(arr.size());
```

the result of `arr.size()` will be some temporary value, such as `42`. You are simply not allowed to take the address of a temporary, regardless of whether the type of `ptr` is correct.

If you want an iterator to the end of the `vector`, you can do:

```
auto i = arr.end();
```

If you actually want a pointer to the end of the `vector`, you can do it like this:

```
int * p = arr.data() + arr.size();
```

Comment: I would definitely [not recommend](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jJD8-u) indexing out of bounds and taking the address. Even if compilers end up giving some leeway for a regular array because C requires it to work, using that with standard containers is a different matter.

Comment: @chris Yes, that was silly. Not sure what I was thinking :p thanks for spotting that. And taking the effort to make a clear demo :)

Comment: and what after inserting or erasing an element?!

Comment: @asmmo Then the iterator/pointer will be invalidated. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: @cigien no I was saying taking this iterator/ptr is a bad idea because of the reason I mentioned

Comment: @asmmo No, there are certainly valid use cases for taking the end iterator (even with the possibility of invalidation). range-for loops do that for example.

Comment: I think it's definitely  better to write `arr.end()` rather than having an iterator that may be invalid anytime for any reason.

Answer (score 4):

[`vector::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) returns `vector::size_type`, an unsigned integer type that is usually `size_t`. But it returns by value and not by reference. So the result of `size()` is a temporary value which will only exist for a short time. So it does not make sense to take the address of that return value and the compiler prohibits this.

How `vector` stores the size internally is up to the STL, implementation dependant. So you can't get a pointer to a size member of `vector`. In fact that variable might not even exist. Or `vector` could internally for example store a size in bytes, not in elements.

If you want to check the size again, then call `size()` again. You cannot get a pointer to a size variable of the `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get a pointer of `arr.size()`, because this method returns rvalue (it is like to get address of number `10`). The only way to change vector size is to add or remove elements from it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're a beginner in C++. The problem you're facing is very common, so you'll have to learn what's wrong. Basically arr.size() return a variable whose type is size_t. That's not important. What's important is how this value is returned. It's something like this:

`size_t size() { return size; }`

So, you return a value, and you want to see where is it stored. It is not stored in memory, because it's returned by value. What's returning by value?

It means that you create a copy of the original variable (in our case, size), and return the copy. However this copy is not stored anywhere (it is, but that's advanced stuff as it involves registers). A variable that is not stored anywhere does not have a memory location, so you just can't take a pointer to that variable.

I hope this cleared it, but if you have any questions just ask it. You may also want to search for things like pass by value, pass by reference, pointers, references in C++, etc if you're interested, but it may give you too much information, and you'd be overwhelmed.